# Is it safe enough?

Tags: java, sql, spring

Is `insert` statement like this is safe enough? Do I have to check if it's not SQL Injectionable?

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void add(String title, String region, String def, String rangeStart,
        String rangeEnd, Date extradition, Date expiration) {
    Session session = null;

    session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session
            .createSQLQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO operators VALUES(NULL,:title,:region,:def,:rangeStart,:rangeEnd, :extradition, :expiration )")
            .setString("title", title).setString("region", region)
            .setString("def", def).setString("rangeStart", rangeStart)
            .setString("rangeEnd", rangeEnd)
            .setDate("extradition", extradition)
            .setDate("expiration", expiration);
    int updated = query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: First, ask yourself this: what *is* [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? Then you should be able to answer yourself :) Note that SQL Injection only covers a very specific scenario - when the *shape* of a query is altered. (Which also means that it could be injection-free but still not "safe".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe enough for SQL Injection attacks. Note that `Query#executeUpdate` will use a `PreparedStatement` behind the scenes for you to set the data for the parameters, which makes this statement safe enough.

`PreparedStatement` will write the `String`s content directly in the specified fields, escaping any undesired value.

Still, note that if you have a bad design of your queries, you will be open to SQL Injection attacks. For example, if you create the query but append the `String` manually:

```
String sqlOpenToSqlInjection = "FROM operators WHERE stringField = " + stringVariable;
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlOpenToSqlInjection);
//code to execute query...
```

More info:

- [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271249/1065197)

---

Looks like you're using Hibernate as well, so it would be better if you save the entity. This would be similar but less code to handle/maintain.

Comment: If there isn't more to come then this is rather a comment. Especially from a 35k+ user.

Comment: @juergend I know, but that's the only sentence to answer OP's question. Should we vote to close? I don't think so because it is a valid question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it is a valid question though, but may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807399/sql-injection-prevention-with-hibernate this one?

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı Hibernate as is already prevents SQL queries for SQL Injection since it uses `PreparedStatement`s for the created queries. That's the answer.